# Eclipse: how to fix package external project dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

I'm having a problem with Eclipse package dependencies and I don't know how to fix it.

My project is dependent on another project (Utils) and everything works fine. However, when I move the java files from the "default package" to another package, all the dependencies of Utils break.

Anyone knows why this happens?

I have the project Utils in the Java Build Path and already tried to remove it and add it again, restart Eclipse... Nothing is working.

Comment: When you say you're moving them "to another package", do you mean that you are, for example, renaming the class `FooUtils` to `com.example.util.FooUtils`? Are you changing the import statements in the classes that use `FooUtils`?

Comment: No, I didn't rename the classes, I just moved them to other non-default package. The import reorganization was being made exclusively by eclipse.

Anyway, I just managed to solve my problem! The java files from the Utils project where in the respective default package. I just put them in a non-default package too. 

Then, when I repeat the process (move the java files from the default to a non-default package in the original project) Eclipse is able to correctly recognize the imports. Thanks anyway, @dcsohl.